# Camel Spring cxf restful web service issue

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

Hi I am trying to consume a cxf spring based web service using camel.
Getting below error on server start up
SEVERE:

```
Context initialization failed
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1680)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsConsumer.<init>(CxfRsConsumer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsEndpoint.createConsumer(CxfRsEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3490)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3420)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3197)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3053)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2848)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: No resource classes found
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:317)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    ... 37 more

Aug 24, 2016 11:19:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1680)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsConsumer.<init>(CxfRsConsumer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsEndpoint.createConsumer(CxfRsEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3490)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3420)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3197)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3053)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2848)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:136)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: No resource classes found
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:317)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Spring 4.2.4, camel 2.17.0 ,cxf 3.1.4

Comment: Have you specified any serviceBeans in your csf service configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've configured resources classes for the cxf component to use. E.g

```
from("cxfrs:http://localhost:8080/?resourceClasses=your.fully.qualified.ClassName")
    .to("mock:in")
```

The resource class you specify needs to be annotated with the jaxrs annotations so cxf can understand it and use it.